# Calling any API after successful login give 401

Tags: flutter, cookies, flutter-web, http-status-code-401, cookie-httponly

I am building an application for Flutter web, the problem is I am able to login into the application successfully (on Chrome web), but after login I get 401 after calling all the APIs(Get & POST). I copied the curl and imported it on Postman and getting the same error. But if I add **cookie** as a header in postman, the API works fine, but when I add cookie as header in code, it gives :

`Refused to set unsafe header "cookie"`

I tried :

```
document.cookie = "<JsessionId>";
```

&

```
headers["Cookie"] = '${LocalData.authorization}';
```

I am calling API using this code :

```
var response = await http.get(_getUri(url, queryParams: queryParams),
    headers: header);
```

I am also getting a warning next to my set-cookie :

`This Set-Cookie header didn't specify a "SameSite" attribute and was defaulted to "SameSite=Lax", and was blocked beacause it came from a cross-site response.`

Comment: The way cookie's should be set is your backend / API should send Set-Cookie header in HTTP response with the cookie, if you try to set it yourself, i guess it would be considered as thrid-party cookie

Comment: @SankethB.K I'm getting cookie as Set-cookie from backend, but with a warning "This Set-Cookie header didn't specify a "SameSite" attribute...."